# How do I make a JSON file out of a list in Python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I try to make a valid JSON file which supposed to look like this one:

```
{
    "video": [
      {"title": "New", "id": "123"},
      {"title": "New", "id": "123"}
    ]
  }
```

out of two lists which contain titles and ids.

```
titles = ['New', 'New']
ids = ['123', '123']
```

I tried it with and a for loop

```
key[] = value
```

But it only gives me the last two items.

I also tried it with

```
newids = {key:value for key, value in titles}
```

Which also does not work.

Can someone give me advice how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `zip()` to pair up the lists:

```
{'video': [{'title': title, 'id': id} for title, id in zip(titles, ids)]}
```

The `video` value is formed by a list comprehension; for every `title, id` pair formed by `zip()` a dictionary is created:

```
>>> titles = ['New', 'New']
>>> ids = ['123', '123']
>>> {'video': [{'title': title, 'id': id} for title, id in zip(titles, ids)]}
{'video': [{'title': 'New', 'id': '123'}, {'title': 'New', 'id': '123'}]}
```

or with a little more interesting content:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> titles = ['Foo de Bar', 'Bring us a Shrubbery!', 'The airspeed of a laden swallow']
>>> ids = ['42', '81', '3.14']
>>> pprint({'video': [{'title': title, 'id': id} for title, id in zip(titles, ids)]})
{'video': [{'id': '42', 'title': 'Foo de Bar'},
           {'id': '81', 'title': 'Bring us a Shrubbery!'},
           {'id': '3.14', 'title': 'The airspeed of a laden swallow'}]}
```

In case you also don't know how to then encode the result to JSON with the [`json` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html), to write to a file use:

```
import json

with open('output_filename.json', 'w', encoding='utf8') as output:
    json.dump(python_object, output)
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't create json data. It creates a python dictionary which should be converted to json to be complete for this question.

Comment: @BryanOakley: right, because that step is the trivial part, and not really part of the question.